# How to store and reset a PHP array pointer?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an associative array, ie

```
$primes = array(
  2=>2,
  3=>3,
  5=>5,
  7=>7,
  11=>11,
  13=>13,
  17=>17,
  // ...etc
);
```

then I do

```
// seek to first prime greater than 10000
reset($primes);
while(next($primes) < 10000) {}
prev($primes);

// iterate until target found
while($p = next($primes)) {
      $res = doSomeCalculationsOn($p);

      if( IsPrime($res) )
          return $p;
}
```

The problem is that IsPrime also loops through the $primes array,

```
function IsPrime($num) {
    global $primesto, $primes, $lastprime;

    if ($primesto >= $num)
        // using the assoc array lets me do this as a lookup
        return isset($primes[$num]);

    $root = (int) sqrt($num);
    if ($primesto < $root)
        CalcPrimesTo($root);

    foreach($primes as $p) {       // <- Danger, Will Robinson!
        if( $num % $p == 0 )
            return false;

        if ($p >= $root)
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

which trashes the array pointer I am iterating on.

I would like to be able to save and restore the array's internal pointer in the IsPrime() function so it doesn't have this side effect.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on array pointers. Use iterators instead.

You can replace your outer code with:

```
foreach ($primes as $p) {
  if ($p > 10000 && IsPrime(doSomeCalculationsOn($p))) {
    return $p;
  }
}
```

Comment: (smacking forehead) OK, this works - I thought foreach() used the array's own pointer, but apparently not.  It *does* reset the array internal pointer, which is kind of an odd side-effect?

Comment: I'm not sure how the internal implementation of foreach works, but it maintains its own state. I don't remember ever using array pointers to traverse lists in PHP.

Comment: Btw. it's kind of odd to use an assoc array for your values. I would use a plain list, and then use in_array() to check if a value exists.

Answer (score 5):

You can "save" the state of the array:

```
$state = key($array);
```

And "restore" (not sure if there's a better method):

```
reset($array);

while(key($array) != $state)
    next($array);
```

Comment: Um... the right effect, but this is O(n) in the size of the array, which makes my algorithm O(n^2) which is unacceptable.

I wonder how hard it would be to extend reset($arr, $key=0) ? (Reset to start or to specified key-value?)

Comment: This answer might not be "best practice", but it's the correct answer to the question, ... imo.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is not an issue and you aren't pushing php memory limits the quickest solution is just to duplicate your primes array and iterate 2 different ones.

```
$awesomePrimes=$primes;
```

Then change globals and foreach in your function to `$awesomePrimes`

Comment: For an array containing 2 million items, that uses an extra 68MB of memory - not the end of the world, but seems wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing one more array of `int -> int`, where the the index is a running number from 0 to *n* and the value is the index of the associative array? So, you would have:

```
$pointer = array(
  0 => 2,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 5,
  // ...
);
```

and instead of referring directly to `$prime` you would use `$prime[$pointer[$i]]`, or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

use a "for" loop for one of your iterations. for example use this loop in your IsPrime method:

```
$primesLength = count($primes); // this is to avoid calling of count() so many times.
for ($counter=0 ; $counter < $primesLength ; $counter++) {
    $p = $primesLength[$counter];
    if( $num % $p == 0 )
            return false;

    if ($p >= $root)
            break;
}
```

this way the internal array pointer will not be used in the method.