# Is this foreach loop responsible for god killing cats?

Tags: php, file, foreach

As taken from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php/4891402#4891402)

Is this similar code killing kittens, too?

```
foreach (file("longFile.txt") as $line) {
    // ouch! Kitten killed
}
```

??

**For those who have no idea what am I talking about:**

Is PHP getting longFile.txt everytime it goes to next line of file or no? Talking about this code:

```
foreach (file("longFile.txt") as $line) {
        // something
}
```

Comment: Going to the next line of file actually would be better than loading it into memory completely, right? See my answer how to do that with PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the linked question the `for` loop incurs a performance hit by calling `count` on every iteration. `foreach` uses internal pointers to iterate through the array passed to it.

In your example `file()` will be called once and the resulting array will be passed to `foreach` which will iterate through it, thus the kittens are saved. Happy Caturday!

Comment: And where's that difference which kills kitten in first case (linked answer)? because it's foreach(){} and not for(){} or because of that file() instead of count() ?

Comment: In the linked question the `for` loop incurs a performance hit by calling `count` on every iteration. `foreach` uses internal pointers to iterate through the array passed to it. It's like giving catnip to a for loop.

Comment: uff, both puppies and kittens are saved :) Happy Caturday!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be killing any kittens, since, in order for PHP to get the following line of the file, it has to know the position of the file pointer since the previous line that was pulled off. You are only advancing the iterator, which maintains a reference to the file object.

Also, it's bad practice to be opening a file like that; you should have a variable to store it in and close it when you're done.

Comment: yes I know, however, in my previous question, someone answered this code.

Comment: Unless my knowledge of PHP is extremely flawed, conceptually, a `foreach` loop is a `for` loop advancing an iterator to the left-hand side of the statement. By that logic, it shouldn't be murdering feline animals. You could verify this for yourself, by checking the number of file handles while the code is running.

Comment: The file is closed before `file()` returns the array. At most it will use a lot of memory which kills puppies, not kittens. Do both and PETA will be all over you.

Comment: @ChetSimpson: so you think that this is killing animals? :( same as for(){} loop and count() ?

Answer (score 1):

Is that file *really* large? Consider:

```
foreach(new SplFileObject($path) as $line) {
    // neither kill puppies nor kittens
}
```

`foreach` works always on the concrete iterator. If you're passing an `array`:

> Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. [(ref)](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

So nor `array` or function call will executed each time the `foreach` steps ahead.

Related: [How to store and reset a PHP array pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328384/367456)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Duff Device to unroll the loop: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%E2%80%99s_Device. This would be faster then foreach and faster then for loop without using count() on each iteration and it would be faster then concatenating and rtrim the string but the same like using implode().

Answer (score 0):

No. There are many reasons why kittens die, but foreach loops are not one of them.